# PrimeNG preselect checkbox based on Array of objects

Tags: angular, primeng

I have matrix of checkboxes, it renders rows based on array of `Permissions` and columns based on array of `Clients`. Since the map table in the db is coming as third array object I push it in `BehaviorSubject<PermissionClient>` and bind it for every `checkbox` as a `ngModel` so it will precheck them. For the `value` of the checkbox I bind an custom object

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-permission>
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{ permission.permissionName }}
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let client of SelectedClients" class="align-center">
          <p-checkbox [value]="{ clientId: client.clientId, permissionId: permission.permissionId }" [(ngModel)]="SelectedRows" (onChange)="onCheckboxChange($event, permission.permissionId, client.clientId)"></p-checkbox>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

So eventually it will map both `Id` and precheck them, but it doesn't work. How can I achieve that?

**PermissionClients interface**

```
export interface PermissionClients {
  clientId: string;
  permissionId: string;
}
```

**And the BehaviorSubject with related get/set**

```
private selectedData: BehaviorSubject<PermissionClients[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
get SelectedRows(): any[] {
  return this.selectedData.getValue();
}

set SelectedRows(val) {
  this.selectedData.next(val);
}
```

When I `console.log` after checkbox check the `SelectedRows` there is exactly 2 the same objects in the array, one from the db and 1 after the check.

Comment: Can you add your scenario into [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Anyway I found the problem. Posting if someone has the same problem. The problem is that since they are exactly the same objects, their reference is not (silly me). Fixed it by creating extended `CheckboxComponent` and overrided the `isChecked()` method for my purposes. Now everything works.